# Postgres 15 authenticating using SSPI instead of username and password

Tags: postgresql

I have been using Postgres 12 on localhost on Windows host with password authentication without any problem.

Then I reinstalled computer and installed Postgres 15.3, repeat the same steps, but it denies to connect me with password authentication and complaining about SSPI authentication.

I created user this way

```
create role foo superuser login;

ALTER USER foo WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'foo';

CREATE DATABASE foo ;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE foo TO foo;
```

Then I tried to connect

```
c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin>set PGPASSWORD=foo
c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin>psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U foo -d foo
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  SSPI authentication failed for user "foo"
```

"c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\data\postgresql.conf":

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)


..............


# - Authentication -

#authentication_timeout = 1min      # 1s-600s
#password_encryption = scram-sha-256    # scram-sha-256 or md5
#db_user_namespace = off

# GSSAPI using Kerberos
#krb_server_keyfile = 'FILE:${sysconfdir}/krb5.keytab'
#krb_caseins_users = off
```

Why it is using SSPI authentication? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you find a `pg_hba.conf` file?   This page says it specifies an auth-method
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that Postgres 15 has password authentication disabled in config. It turned out that Postgres was installed as part of other product with non standard configuration.

You can enable it in "c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\data\pg_hba.conf"

by replacing the following lines

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            sspi map=domain
host    all             all             ::1/128                 sspi map=domain
```

with

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            password
host    all             all             ::1/128                 password
```

Comment: How did you install?  I've never seen a standard installation use sspi by default.

Comment: It turned out that Postgres was installed as part of other product even with non standard configuration.